# Append timestamp to output file in function

Tags: shell

I need a encryption function adjustment so the output file has a timestamp in the file name.

```
function gpgencrypt {
   gpg --homedir /root/.gnupg/ --recipient "$RECIPIENT" --output "$OUTPUT/$(basename $FILE).pgp" --gnupg --armor --encrypt "$FILE"
}
```

Comment: If you could perhaps expand/clarify your question a little it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATE="$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")"

function gpgencrypt {
   gpg --homedir /root/.gnupg/ --recipient "$RECIPIENT" --output "$OUTPUT/$(basename $FILE)_$DATE.pgp" --gnupg --armor --encrypt "$FILE"
}
```